# What is the default select of XSLT apply-templates?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

The identity template looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Does `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />` select more than `<xsl:apply-templates />`, or could the identity template have been like this?

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

What exactly is selected when I do the following?

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Does `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />` select more than
>   `<xsl:apply-templates />`, or could the identity template have been
>   like this?

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
```

and this is a shorter former of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
```

and this is a equivalent to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="* | text() | comment() | processing-instruction()"/>
```

As we see from the last instruction, the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction you are asking about, doesn't select any attributes, therefore it cannot be used as a shorthand for:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
```

Comment: @OP: P.S. this is defined at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules: "In the absence of a select attribute, the xsl:apply-templates instruction processes all of the children of the current node, including text nodes. ..." Note that attribute nodes are *not* considered children of their parent element.

Comment: @LarsH, Yes, but sometimes readers find quoting the Specs to be "intimidating" :)

Comment: Yeah, if I had to choose between only quoting the Spec and only explaining what it means, I would choose your answer (unless I thought the implications of the spec were very easy to understand on this point). However in conjunction with a helpful explanation, I think pointing users to the primary material helps them "learn how to fish." The OP here seems to be an accomplished programmer, who shouldn't be afraid of the spec. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The default select for `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is just `"node()"`, it doesn't include attributes.

Comment: Ah, then makes perfect sense then :)

Answer (score 2):

The [default selection of apply-templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-apply-templates) is `node()`, which is shorthand for `child::node()`. This XPath expressions is evaluated as follows:

- First, all nodes from the "child" [axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) are taken. This are all the direct children of the current element, i.e. other elements, text, and comments, but *not* the attributes.
- Then this node set is filtered with the [node test](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) "node()". In this case, no elements are filtered because that test matches everything.

So with `<xsl:apply-templates />`, templates for the child elements are applied but not for the attributes. In case of the copy template this would mean that the attributes are not copied.