# How to sort xml using a tag field?

Tags: xml, sorting

This is my xml file -

```
<document>
  <file>
    <ref>2</ref>
  </file>
  <file>
    <ref>1</ref>
  </file>
</document>
```

Now i want output in this format after sorting by `<ref>` tag:

```
<document>
  <file>
    <ref>1</ref>
  </file>
  <file>
    <ref>2</ref>
  </file>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this template in combination with the [*identity template*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12707630/1305969):

```
<xsl:template match="/document">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="file">
            <xsl:sort select="ref" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The *identity template* copies all nodes for which no other template matches. The template above matches the root `document` node, copies it, and then applies all templates only on the `file` elements. The `xsl:sort` does sort the `file` elements before applying the templates with the sort key `ref` and the implied default order `ascending`.

---

So the whole XSLT stylesheet could look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="ref"/>
    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/document">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="file">
                <xsl:sort select="ref" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now pass both files (the XML and the XSLT stylesheet) to an XSLT processor of your choice and you'll get the desired (sorted) output.

To preserve CDATA elements, add the element's name to a `cdata-section-elements="..."` attribute in an `xsl:output` global element.

Comment: Can you please explain this since I am new to xml

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @zx485

Comment: Can you also tell how to apply this? I have the xml which i posted on the question now if I want to sort it then how to apply your solution?

Comment: Thanks. My xml uses CDATA[[]] ref. but after applying this xslt they've been removed from the output xml. Is there any way to keep CDATA tags as well after sorting.